# Arctan with minus sign in the exponents

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

Is there an easy or quick way to see that
$$
-\int\frac{4\lambda e^{-(\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})}}{1+e^{-2(\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})}}\, dx = -4\arctan(e^{\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda}})\tag{1}?
$$

Okay, when I know that $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, then by the chain rule, I can differentiate the right hand side of (1) to get
$$
-4\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(e^{\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda}})=-4\lambda e^{\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda}}\frac{1}{1+e^{2(\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})}}
$$

But what about the minus signs in the exponents appearing in the integrand?

Comment: $$\frac{e^{-u}}{1+e^{-2u}}\cdot\frac{e^{2u}}{e^{2u}}=\frac{e^{-u}e^{2u}}{e^{2u}+e^{-2u}e^{2u}}=\frac{e^u}{e^{2u}+1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\int\frac{4\lambda e^{-(\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})}}{1+e^{-2(\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})}}\, dx = 4\arctan(e^{\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda}})+C.$$
This is easily observed simply by multiplying both the numerator and denominator of the integrand by
$$e^{2(\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})}:$$
our integral becomes
$$\int\frac{4\lambda e^{(\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})}}{1+e^{2(\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})}}\, dx$$ which is easily dealt with the substitution $u=e^{(\mu+\lambda x+\frac{t}{\lambda})}$ if it isn't clear immediately.

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :-)